# class is not public in my package and cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the following [ControlFX](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/e47cc550571abffff0ee56ea0f27683655cb076a/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs.java?at=default#cl-532) project. Hence, created a `Dialogs.java` class in my package and pasted the code from there.

Since I am not Inside the package `org.controlsfx.dialog` , I have to do the following:

***import org.controlsfx.dialog.LightweightDialog;***

And I am getting the following error as shown in the image below: [image]

When I went inside the package `org.controlsfx.dialog` and opened, `LightweightDialog.class`,

I wasn't able to make the class public.

How should I overcome this situation? Please advise.

Comment: Why are you copying the source code?

Comment: @James_D Am I not supposed to copy the source code?

Comment: No, just download the jar and put it in your classpath. Then use it.

Comment: @James_D I have jar file in my Netbeans Project but still when I put the code mentioned below by you below generates lot of errors in my code.

Comment: Updated. If you still get errors comment on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the class is not public, it is not part of the public API, so it's not intended (or really possible) for you to use.

To use a lightweight dialog in ControlsFX, you can either use the `Dialogs` class API and call the `lightweight()` method as part of the creation of your dialog, or you can call one of the `Dialog` constructors which takes a flag for the `lightweight` property.

Here's a complete example using the `Dialogs` fluent API:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);

            TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
            Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
            BorderPane tab1Root = new BorderPane();
            Button showDialogButton = new Button("Enter message...");
            VBox messages = new VBox(3);
            HBox buttons = new HBox(5);
            buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));
            buttons.getChildren().add(showDialogButton);
            tab1Root.setBottom(buttons);

            ScrollPane messageScroller = new ScrollPane();
            messageScroller.setContent(messages);
            tab1Root.setCenter(messageScroller);

            tab1.setContent(tab1Root);

            Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
            tab2.setContent(new TextField("This is tab 2"));

            tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

            showDialogButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                String response = Dialogs.create()
                        .lightweight()
                        .owner(tab1)
                        .masthead("Enter a new message")
                        .message("Enter your new message:")
                        .showTextInput();
                if (response != null) {
                    messages.getChildren().add(new Label(response));
                }
            });

            root.setCenter(tabPane);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Using the `Dialog` constructor you'd do something like this, though it's a lot more work:

```
// params are owner, title, lightweight:
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(someNode, "Dialog", true);
// lots of code here to configure dialog...
Action response = dialog.show();
```

The real beauty of ControlsFX is the very comprehensive documentation. Just check the [Javadocs for Dialogs](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs.html) and for [Dialog](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialog.html).