# How to use a class in an imported jar?

Tags: android, jar

What I am doing:  Call the method inside the class in a very simple jar from main Activity. (The jar will be used as sdk to make connection with a server but right now is for testing)

Error message
[image: Error message] 
This is all the code in my jar, just 1 class
[image: This all the code in my jar, just 1 class]

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413776/is-there-a-solution-to-cannot-access-init-it-is-private-in-xyz), and changed the class into singleton pattern and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386576/classes-cannot-be-accessed-from-outside-package/42554338), and make everything in the class public. I also found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418555/class-isge) but same error different issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create class as `public class` to make it accessible. In java if you don't provide any access modifier it becomes `default`.

Refer Java Access Modifiers [here](https://www.journaldev.com/2345/java-access-modifiers#java-access-modifiers-8211-default-access)

```
public class Jartest{

  //Your Implementation

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to create the class with public modifier, all classes must be warped inside a package. Otherwise it becomes default package and there is no way to access it beside reflection. In another word, when you create the jar, create the class inside a package and Android studio should be able to import the package and use the class inside the jar.